# Is there a formula for the binomial expansion of $(a-b)^n$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, binomial-theorem

Like there is a formula for the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^n$ that can be neatly and compactly be written as a summation, does there exist an equivalent formula for $(a-b)^n$ ?

Comment: Try letting $x = -b$.

Comment: Yes, just substitute for b for -b

Comment: Ok...so you know the formula for $(a+b)^n$...now,try this...$(a-b)^n=\{a+(-b)\}^n$....Now,you know the formula.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**:$$\\ (a+b)^{ n }=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \binom{n}{k} { a }^{ n-k } } { b }^{ k }$$
now substitute here  $b=-b$ $$(a-b)^{ n }=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ k }\binom{n}{k} { a }^{ n-k } } { b }^{ k }$$

Comment: This answer could be made clearer. By setting $b=-b$ you are effectively setting $b=0$. While I realise your intent, it could lead to confusion for others.

Comment: @WillR,thank you,but think it is quite clear what i've meant

Comment: maybe $b\mapsto -b$ would be more clear notation

Answer (score 5):

$$(a-b)^n = (a+ (-b))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^k (-b)^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}a^kb^{n-k} = $$